# How do you find the RTH of this?

Tags: circuit-analysis, thevenin

[image]

I suddenly got confused while practice solving using Thevenin method.

[image]

Comment: Where are you stuck? Do you remember the procedure for finding Rth and what you do with the sources (i.e your first diagram)?  If follow the procedure you can see Rth by inspection.

Comment: Maybe re-draw your top diagram with R2 and R3 to the left of R1.  That should help you see the answer.

Comment: Looks like R2 and R3 in the top diagram are irrelevant. Why did you add a current source at those unlabeled nodes?